# Deleting huge amounts of Documents in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, performance

I have been working on a project. Where my user may need to delete 50k+(I mean huge amount of documents linked to liking of post, if the post is deleted the liked documents of that post will be deleted) documents. I saw It takes huge amounts of time. Needs to mention- my Like documents' collection have multiple indexes.

My question - is there any other way of deleting the Like documents total amount 50k+ or should I use a delete marking field and a `TTL index` field by update operation or is there any other manual way which may schedule delete the documents operation from outer source?

Unfortunately updating 55485 docs takes 15.3 seconds and deleting these files take 6 min + .
In my test `like collection` I have 20 Millions of documents.Yet it is so bad performance on local host db server.

Document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "date" : ISODate("2019-07-17T14:30:41.155Z"),
    "isPresent" : false,
    "tags" : [ 
        "9301", 
        "8175", 
        "1374"
    ],
    "userId" : 9969
}
```

Indexes

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "tags" : 1
        },
        "name" : "tags",
        "background" : false
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "isPresent" : 1
        },
        "name" : "isPresent",
        "background" : false
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "userId" : 1
        },
        "name" : "userId",
        "background" : false
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "date" : 1,
            "isPresent" : 1
        },
        "name" : "dateAndIsPresent",
        "background" : false
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "isPresent" : 1,
            "tags" : 1
        },
        "name" : "isPresentAndTags",
        "background" : false
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "removeTTl" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "removeTTl_1",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 30.0
    }
    
]
```

Comment: 50k is not so huge. How long does it take and what would you expect?

Comment: I added more info to my question. Unfortunately updating 55485 docs takes 15.3 seconds and deleting these files take 6 min + seconds. Both update and delete take terrible amount of time. In my application I can not allow  more than 15 milliseconds for any background process. Even 15 milliseconds is huge time. Any db operation more than that needs to handle different way.

Comment: are you issuing 50k delete commands or 1 delete command? pls add sample documents and your delete command so ppl can get a better idea of what's happenning.

Comment: On single doc deleteOne operation it takes max 8 milliseconds.

Comment: "I can not allow more than 15 milliseconds" - really? You may consider the [In-Memory Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/), or any other in-Memory database.

Comment: How do you delete the data? It looks like you run 50k times the `deleteOne` command, which is the worst you can do. Use `deleteMany` or [Bulk Operation Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I used `deleteMany`, 6 min + is the result of this.